# Removing images created by Linux Deploy

Tags: applications, files, delete

I have SM-G900F on Lineage Oreo. I installed Linux Deploy and left the path to `${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}/linux.img`, and I removed the app for a second time. Now, I still have the `linux.img` in my memory, but I can't delete it because I don't know the path to where was it created, while in the installer app can't find it.

Going to Settings -> Storage and tapping on Linux Deploy doesn't work, I can't see more than 50 MB used for it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I made it to delete the file using ES File explorer.